# I want to change value false to true?

Tags: javascript

I want to change value of `isPremium` to `true`.
How will I do that?

```
const users = [
  { isPremium: false }, 
  { isPremium: false }, 
  { isPremium: false }, 
  { isPremium: false }, 
  { isPremium: false }, 
];
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
users = users.map(x=> x.isPremium = true) :
```

Also, use let instead of const

Answer (score 0):

Since all values are replacing without any condition, i have used `_` in the map function to indicate the unused variable

```js
let users = [{ isPremium: false },{ isPremium: false },{ isPremium: false }, { isPremium: false }, { isPremium: false }];
users = users.map(_=> ({'isPremium':true}));
console.log(users)
```

**METHOD 2**

Using forEach

```js
var users = [{ isPremium: false },{ isPremium: false },{ isPremium: false }, { isPremium: false }, { isPremium: false }];
users.forEach((item) => item.isPremium = true);
console.log(users)
```

`forEach:` Iterates and transform the array and does not return anything.

`map:` This iterates over a array and returns another list of the same size with the transformed values.

**METHOD 3**

```js
let users = [{ isPremium: false },{ isPremium: false },{ isPremium: false }, { isPremium: false }, { isPremium: false }];
users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users).replaceAll("false","true"));
console.log(users)
```

Comment: thanks for this bro, this works with my code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
users.forEach(user => user.isPremium = true);
```

Shortest answer I could think of, `users` can stay at `const` as well with this because we are just mutating the list not reassigning it to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to toggle any boolean value in your array.

```
function toggleBool(array, pram) {
  array.forEach(item => item[pram] = !item[pram]);
}
```

In this example you can do this:

```
toggleBool(users, 'isPremium')
```